# How to disable CSRF in Spring Boot 3 only for tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm writing tests for an application using Spring Boot 3.1.2. The application has csrf enabled, but the authorization in the tests fails when csrf is turned on, therefore I want to turn it off for the tests only.

My security config currently looks like this:

```
@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers(openUrls).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasAuthority(applicationRoleKey))
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth -> oauth
            .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())));
    return http.build();
}
```

A sample test that is failing (get 406 instead of 400):

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(authorities = "user=admin")
void asAdmin_canGetPhoto() throws Exception {
  mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/photo")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

What's the recommended way to disable CSRF only for tests? I can only find solutions using outdated versions of Spring Security.

Thanks for any guidance!

EDIT: Solved by adding `.with(csrf())` to the tests.

Comment: If you will have something like this for integration test a specific `@Profile(“test”)`  also 2 security configuration one for test(where you will disable csrf) and another as usually with csrf enabled. I think it is a good way to do it.

Comment: Can you show your tests? Can't you add CSRF tokens to the test? You could also try defining an additional `SecurityFilterChain` for tests.

Comment: I was really hoping I could define a single SecurityFilterChain, and override it somehow (i.e. with a @TestConfiguration). I've added a test now @dan1st.

Comment: What stops you from using `.with(csrf())` in the test and why do you not like adding a second `SecurityFilterChain`?

Comment: Thanks @dan1st, using `.with(csrf())` solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved by adding `.with(csrf())` to the tests instead of disabling csrf for the tests.